# The program is arbitrarily coming out of the recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

See I am trying to print the different ways the number n can be printed with the maximum number in it to be 4.
My program subtracts the no `here(4)` in a loop and then prints 4 at end and sends the remaining number `here(2)` to the same function with max as 3 ,2 ,1.
when max is 1 it just prints all 1s.

When I enter n=6 it displays output

> 2
>   1 1 4

where it should display

> 2 4
>   1 1 4

I don't know why this behavior is coming , it is a simple recursion and I also have checked a lot for errors.

This is the code

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void comp(int n,int k)
{
if(n>=k&&k!=0&&k!=1&&n!=0)
{

    for(int i=1;i<=(n/k);i++)
    {
        for(int l=k-1;l>=1;l--)
        {
            comp(n-(i*k),l);

        }

        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            cout<<k<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}
if(k==1)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"1 ";
    }

}

}
int main()
{
int n;
while(cin>>n)
{
    comp(n,4);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Step through the code using print statements to locate your issue. If you can't figure it out from there, then post a more specific question.

Comment: It's a pain in the neck with recursive functions and nested loops, you step through the code line by line in a debugger to see what happens and what values the variables have. Note that it would help to have better naming of variables and some comments, would you understand the code if you came back to it in a year? Longer variable names have no impact on performance or space consumption of the executable program.

Comment: @RohanAggarwal : Is it working properly for n = 5 and k = 3? What about (6,3) or (5,4). If yes, then try and find out what is changing in these inputs. If not, then use smaller inputs until your recursion is shallow enough that you can step through it easily. Also follow Joachim's advice above.

Comment: I found my mistake Thanx a lot :)